# How to convert SOAP response to XML or JSON format?

Tags: php, json, xml, soap

```
<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:body>
        <ns1:mbillcommandresponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.mysoap.com/SoapService/">
            <ReturnValues>
                <name>status</name>
                <value>TEHNICAL_ERROR</value>
            </ReturnValues>
            <ReturnValues>
                <name>description</name>
                <value>Please contact your administrator</value>
            </ReturnValues>
        </ns1:mbillcommandresponse>
    </soapenv:body>
</soapenv:envelope>
```

Above I got response in my CURL response. Here is my PHP code:

```
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    //$result = $xml->xpath('//name'); //echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); exit;
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://www.mysoap.com/SoapService/');
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//returnvalues') as $item) {
        $json = json_encode($item);
        $convrt_arr = json_decode($json, true);
        break;
    }
    print_r($json); exit;
```

On my above code I got empty json. Could you please help me.

Comment: can i see data in `$xml->xpath('//returnvalues')` ?

Comment: *btw* Soap is an XML format, but here are special libraries like [ext/soap](http://php.net/manual/de/book.soap.php) to handle it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. It prints `{"name":"status","value":"TEHNICAL_ERROR"}` on my machine.

Comment: @SupunPraneeth I have posted my SOAP response data. You could check there my `returnvalues` data

Comment: Why not use standard SoapClient instead of CURL? That way you can convert the answer directly to PHP objects (given you provide mappings for the types). Having an address of SOAP web service you can get all the necessary work done for you by libraries like https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator

Comment: thr is no error in code able to see result: https://3v4l.org/322K6

Comment: Oh!! Really sorry for that. It is my mistake. Above code is working fine. But in my SOAP response it's coming `ReturnValues` When I copied from `inspect element` its looking small letter. :(

Answer (score 2):

Your question edit is a big clue. You changed the XML from having lowercase to CamelCase elements. Change:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//returnvalues') as $item) {
```

to:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//ReturnValues') as $item) {
```

and it will work. Xpath queries are case sensitive.

Comment: Fairly curious -- why the down vote? If the value of `$response` was what the OP expected, his code would generate a different result than it is.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My code was right. I have edited my question. Could you please check and edit your answer

Comment: Sure thing. Edit complete.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$response = '<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:body>
        <ns1:mbillcommandresponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.mysoap.com/SoapService/">
            <returnvalues>
                <name>status</name>
                <value>TEHNICAL_ERROR</value>
            </returnvalues>
            <returnvalues>
                <name>description</name>
                <value>Please contact your administrator</value>
            </returnvalues>
        </ns1:mbillcommandresponse>
    </soapenv:body>
</soapenv:envelope>';
$response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $response);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$body = $xml->xpath('//returnvalues');
$json = json_encode((array)$body); 
print_r($json);
```